# Trying to identify a juvenile SF from around 1950-1960. Pirates hijacking spaceships cruisers on the Earth-Moon (or inner planets) route

Tags: story-identification, novel

When I was a boy (so, some 55 years ago; 1960-1970) I read a novel (written probably in the '50s or 'early '60s) about pirates hijacking spaceship cruise ships on the Earth-Moon route (or perhaps also to other inner planets of the solar system.).

The story was told from the point of view of a boy whose father was an astronomer on the Moon. Details that I remember: a crew member trying to make head or tails of Emmanuel Kant's Critique of Pure Reason, and an astronomer being badly burned by his telescope of the moon pointing directly to the sun.

I seem to remember that the author was Jack Vance, but I could be completely mistaken about that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is *[Vandals of the Void](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1619471353)* (1953) by Jack Vance.

> Fifteen-year-old Dick Murdock travels aboard the African Star to the
> Moon, to meet his father Dr. Paul Murdock—Chief Astronomer at the
> Lunar Observatory.
>
> En route, the African Star finds the hulk of a spaceship hanging in
> space, blasted open with all hands killed. It’s the work of space
> pirates, led by the malevolent Basilisk!
>
> Dick applies himself to uncovering who—or what—the Basilisk is? The
> stakes are enormously high; while prospecting for lunar tourmalines
> high on a lunar cliff with Crazy Sam Baxter, someone tries to kill him
> with a giant falling rock.

One of the crew is reading Kant

> *Dick twisted to look at the bosun’s book. “What are you reading?”.
> The bosun was obviously relieved at the change of subject. “Kant’s
> Critique of Pure Reason. It’s the finest book in the world for a
> spaceman.”*

A scientist on the moon is [very badly burned](https://www.youtube.com/watch?si=45fSE2QuUvxHTJuA&t=45&v=RhOht9t0zSU&feature=youtu.be).

> *Because if, by some mistake or neglect, the telescope were pointed at
> the sun without the shield, the sunlight focusing inside the cage
> would burn the observer and all his instruments to a cinder.*
>
> *That, regrettably, is what happened to Dr. Vrosnek. By some strange
> oversight —" he repeated the words thoughtfully “— a very strange
> oversight, he neglected to use the sun-shield, and he was burned to
> death.”*

Comment: Yes, that sounds exactly like the novel I remember, thank you!